# Are my half siblings related to my half brother?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

My parents Bianca and Ivan are currently married and have always been since before I was born. Both of my parents have had previous relationships in the past. Bianca had a previous relationship with Henry and have a son named John, making John my half brother. Ivan had a previous relationship with Alicia, and have two sons named Frank and Ernest, making Frank and Ernst my half brothers. After that, Ivan met Katy and have a daughter named Pamela, making Pamela my half sister. So basically, I have one brother from my mom’s side and two brothers and one sister from my dad’s side. John knows who my other half siblings are but he doesn’t know them at all and he barely sees them. Is he related to them?Is there a term for this relationship?  I suspect he really isn’t but I’m just curious.

Comment: I am at a loss. How is this a question about English?

Comment: @RegDwight I am wanting to know if there is a term for this relationship in English Language.

Answer (score 2):

According to today's standards, they're not truly related.

However, they are members of the same *clan*.

Also, less than 500 years ago, if John and Pamela had a relationship, it would have been considered incestuous: a sibling was a true sibling once he or she had been recognized as such. This had to do with the Christian view of the family as a concept, I think (which is why, for instance, Shakespeare's Hamlet views his mother's marriage to his uncle as incestuous).

Comment: It’s not incestuous...they’re not blood related whatsoever...so they’re not really siblings.

Comment: @Samuel: Do PLEASE re-read the answer. Goodness gracious.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on your understanding of the word **related**.

Oxford defintes related as:

> [related](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/related) -
>   adjective - Belonging to the same family, group, or type; connected.

In that sense you are absolutely related, but in another sense you might not be.  Some people use the term related to refer to primary familial connections (father, mother, sister, brother, cousin.)  In the eyes of such a person, you wouldn't be related unless you shared familial DNA.

In my opinion that definition is too narrow.  Ultimately, all humans are related, and we are genetically related to other mammals.  The important thing is, are you family?

Comment: I am asking you if my half brother is related to my half siblings?

Comment: When you say "Oxford" what do you mean? There are all kinds of dictionaries some highly regarded, such as the Oxford English Dictionary (27 volumes in print format, also online), some awful, which trade off the name "Oxford". There is no protection for the name as there is for "Champagne" and no guarantee that the publishers have ever been anywhere near Oxford, England.